# c++ convert string to LPCWSTR in FindWindow

Tags: c++, string, winapi

i am trying to read Window title from txt file

i will use GetTitleWidnow to get window title using string

i tried this but it didnt display menu in application

```
   ostringstream GetTitleWidnow;
    GetTitleWidnow << "MainSvrt on port 51752";
    LPCWSTR LMainSvrtTitle;
std::string SMainSvrtTitle = GetTitleWidnow.str();
LMainSvrtTitle = (LPCWSTR)SMainSvrtTitle.c_str();


HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL,LMainSvrtTitle);
HMENU hCurrent = GetMenu(hWnd);
HMENU hNew = CreateMenu();
AppendMenu(hCurrent, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (unsigned int)hNew, TEXT("Menu"));
AppendMenu(hNew, MF_STRING, MYMENU_Reload, TEXT("Reload Config"));
AppendMenu(hNew, MF_STRING, MYMENU_Credits, TEXT("Credits"));
DrawMenuBar(hWnd);
```

but when i try

```
 HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL,TEXT("MainSvrt on port 51752"));
```

i get it working fine and it display menu in application

Comment: If you need the stringstream and string, you can use `std::owstringstream` and `std::wstring`. Casting a narrow C string to a wide one is a very bad idea.

Comment: I don't think its relevant per say but you misspelled GetTitleWindow

Comment: tried  std::stringstream , but it didnt work and std::owstringstream not found in std

Comment: i dont think so misspelled it

Comment: All you need is `FindWindow(NULL, L"MainSvrt on port 51752")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either use Microsoft's CString which automatically converts between wide and narrow characters, or use the `MultiByteToWideChar` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use ATL, please try CA2W, CW2A, it's so easy to use.